# Adding get_results to WordPress REST API

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I have custom function where I retrieve guid's attached to each post. Now I want to add this on WordPress API.

```
global $wpdb;

$post_id= $object['id'];
$sql = "SELECT post_content FROM wp_posts WHERE id = $post_id";

$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

foreach ($results as $result) {
    $content = $result->post_content;

    $needle = 'gallery_ids="';

    $offset = strpos($content,$needle);

    if($offset>=0){
        $offset += strlen($needle);

        $l = strpos($content,'"',$offset);
        $l -= $offset;
        $content = substr($content,$offset,$l);
        $content = explode(",",$content);
        function filterGuid($var) {return is_numeric($var);}
        $content = array_filter($content,"filterGuid");

        for ($x = 0; $x <= count($content) -1; $x++) {
            $guids = "SELECT guid FROM wp_posts WHERE id IN ('$content[$x]')";
            $gui_results = $wpdb->get_results($guids);

            foreach ($gui_results as $result) {
                echo $result->guid;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What changes should I make to add it? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

A few steps to help you out:

1. Register your function with the rest api. Replace endpoint_group and endpoint with any value to use.

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'register_function_name' );

function register_function_name() {
    register_rest_route( 'endpoint_group', '/endpoint', array(
        'methods' => 'POST', //Whatever Method you want
        'callback' => 'callback_function' //Function to call       
    ));
}
```

2. Alter your function to return the results instead of echo them.

```
function callback_function(){

global $wpdb;

$post_id= $object['id']; //Change this to get the data from the api call ex: $post_id = $_POST['id']
$sql = "SELECT post_content FROM wp_posts WHERE id = $post_id";

$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

    foreach ($results as $result) {
    $content = $result->post_content;

    $needle = 'gallery_ids="';

    $offset = strpos($content,$needle);

    if($offset>=0){
        $offset += strlen($needle);

        $l = strpos($content,'"',$offset);
        $l -= $offset;
        $content = substr($content,$offset,$l);
        $content = explode(",",$content);
        function filterGuid($var) {return is_numeric($var);}
        $content = array_filter($content,"filterGuid");

        for ($x = 0; $x <= count($content) -1; $x++) {
            $guids = "SELECT guid FROM wp_posts WHERE id IN ('$content[$x]')";
            $gui_results = $wpdb->get_results($guids);

            foreach ($gui_results as $result) {
                $results[] = $result->guid;
            }
        }
    }
    }

   wp_send_json_success($results, 200);
}
```